# Minimal example for amazon FPS using python and boto?

Tags: python, boto, amazon-fps

Someone could show me how can I use python's boto library for an amazon FPS transaction on which I'm the caller and the recipient? Sadly [this exelent documentation](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/) doesn't mention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the examples there are pretty minimal, boto provides pretty excellent API documentation, and it looks like FPS is no exception. The fps sub-package has its own [section](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/fps.html).

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the [Amazon-FPS-specific code for django-merchant](https://github.com/agiliq/merchant/blob/master/billing/integrations/amazon_fps_integration.py).

This code uses boto, and you can see examples of opening the fps connection, making a purchase, and making a credit. (Or you could just download and use django-merchant.)